# make the map/area element rotate with native javascript and css

Tags: css, rotation

We have this htmls in our page:

```
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="mouse_target">
    <img style="-moz-user-select: none; border: medium none; width: 27px; height: 35px;" usemap="#imgmap1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9eo1.png">
    <map name="imgmap1"><area href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor: pointer;" title="" shape="poly" coords="11,25,22,11,11,1,1,11,11,25,11,33"></map>
</div>
```

And the css:

```css
    #img,#mouse_target{
        width:27px;
        height:35px;
        position:absolute;
        left:40px;
        top:100px;
    }
    #img{
        background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9eo1.png") no-repeat;
        -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
#mouse_target{
    opacity:0.01;
}
#mouse_target map{
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#mouse_target map area{
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXSeL/)

Now,we have two problems:

1. implement the rotate across browser

   Since the -moz-transform does not work on ie.
2. make the `div#mouse_target` or `div#mouse_target map` or
   `div#mouse_target map area` rotate with the `div#img`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Whether `transform` works on IE depends on which IE you're talking about, because [all latest version of modern browsers support `transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility), provided proper prefix.

Comment: I  have  tried  add  transform  to  the  map  and  the  area  element, but  it  does  not  work.

Comment: I don't know why, but `i.stack.imgur.com` always give me 403 here, so I can't efficiently test your code, but from what I see, you're not rotating `map`, only `area` (`#mouse_target map area` points to `area`). Maybe you mean `#mouse_target map, #mouse_target area`?

Comment: Even I add the rotating to  map and area element,it does not change.